# Add required input on html form of a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spreadsheet

I'm trying to do an HTML Form on a google spreadsheet, the problem is that the "required" attribute doesn't work.

Currently when I submit the form the only field being required is the radio input "type".
I want all the input to be required and to prevent the form from being submited if one of thoses field are empty.

It would be nice if someone can check what is my mistake. Thanks !

Here is my html :

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="fr">

  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">   
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
<div class="container"> 

<h3 class="display-4 mb-3">Nouvelle Transaction</h3>

<div class="userform">


  <div class= row>

    <div class="col">
      <label for="date">Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date1" required>
    </div>



    <div class="col">
    <label for="client1">Client</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="client1" value="" required>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>


<label class ="mt-4" for="type">Type</label>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
  <input type="radio" id="credit" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="achat"required>
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Achat</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline ml-3">
  <input type="radio" id="debit" name="type" class="custom-control-input" value="paiement">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="debit">Paiement</label>
</div>
</div>

 <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <label for="date">Montant</label>

<div class="mb-3 input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control rounded-right" id="montant1" required>
</div>

    
    
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" id="mainButton">Valider</button>
  
    
   
</div>
</div>
   
    

    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <script>
 
 
 function validationBouton(){
    
    if(validate()){
    
    var date11 = document.getElementById("date1");
    var client11 = document.getElementById("client1");
    var type11 = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]:checked').value;
    var montant11 = document.getElementById("montant1");
    
    var rowData = {date1 : date11.value,client1 : client11.value,type1 : type11,montant1 : montant11.value};
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterValidate).addNewRow(rowData);
    }  else {

    //later
    //$('#errorNotification').toast('show');
    
    }
    
    }
    
    function afterValidate(e){
      var date11 = document.getElementById("date1");
      var client11 = document.getElementById("client1");
      var type11 = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]:checked');
      var montant11 = document.getElementById("montant1");
      
      date11.value = "";
      client11.value = "";
      type11.checked = false;
      montant11.value = "";
      
      //$('#successNotification').toast('show');
    }
    
    
    function validate(){
      var champsAValider = document.querySelectorAll("#userform input");
      return Array.prototype.every.call(champsAValider,function(el){
         return el.checkValidity();
      
      });
    
    }

    
    document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click",validationBouton);
    
 </script>



</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot of the form]

Comment: You have too much code. Simplify it and you might get an answer

Comment: You should also wrap the code that has all the input fields in `<form></form>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @SteveTomlin I removed unnecessary lines

Comment: @S.Ramjit when i wrap it in <form> the form disappear when i submit it

Answer (score 0):

You need the `form` element to tell the browser to look at the fields to validate them. The form disappears on clicking submit because technically there's supposed to be an action attribute.

To override the default behavior, include on the `onsubmit` attribute in the form tag that tells it which function to run when the submit button on the form is clicked.

Try clicking the submit button without entering anything and then enter information and test that the form doesn't disappear, in the example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="return myFormHandler();">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

<script>
function myFormHandler(){
  return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```